# RS422 Pan & Tilt always repeats commands instead of answering

Tags: serial-port, com-port

I followed [this](https://www.serialporttool.com/sptblog/?p=4830) Tutorial to test the RS422 connection to my Pan&Tilt.

This is the output of some of the test commands.

[image: Output]

Is is noticable, that the Pan&Tilt always repeats my commands. As far as my knowledge goes, this is not always the case. The "04 3F" command makes it move, so this does not require an answer, "53 00" however is a question as to what the current angle of the Pan&Tilt currently is, this does require an answer that is not the repetition of the question.

The connection to my PC is done via [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/d73f/0900766b80da71a2.pdf) USB-Connector.

Looking for any tips as to what I might need to look into.

Comment: Is there any hardware mode setting or cable/pin connection that is looping back and receiving the data you sent?

Comment: Not of my knowledge, the cables between Pan&Tilt and Connector are connected directly to one another without any possibility of looping back. The P&T is a "Black-Box" unfortunately, I do not know what happens inside it, as it is a finished product.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

And for anyone with a future similar problem - dont take product descriptions as ground truth.

After the contact to the support I was told, that there was no chance the hardware was the problem, as it and the delivered software to control the P&T worked flawlessly in the past.
But - just to be 101% sure - we could check the DIP-Lever inside the P&T.

Turns out the "Default" Settings were not so default after all.. the P&T was expecting RS485 inputs (besides telling that RS422 would be the default setting), that is why connecting TX+ to "+" and TX- or RX- to "-" resulted in a movement but not any response.

So, long story short, I changed the DIP-Levers to the RS-422 protocol and connected
TX+/TX- from the USB-Converter to TX+/TX- from the P&T
RX+/RX- from the USB-Converter to RX+/RX- from the P&T
and it worked without issue.